# Ajax If Statement Issue

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am making a website where depending on what a column says in the database the javascript will perform a curtain task (using ajax). This is going fine, however in the if statement, when the requirements are met, it keeps repeating it since it's inside the setInterval. It is probably easier for me to just paste the code and give you a chance to take a look at it.

```
setInterval(function(){

    $("#div").load("content.php");

    if ($('#div:contains("hello")').length > 0) {
        alert("Hello, world!");
    }

}, 200);
```

As you can see above, the alert is alerted forever at the speed the interval is set to. Sorry if I have been unclear, I have no idea how to ask questions properly on forums.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use the setInterval to check if the div has gotten its content already. 
This can be solved with a callback (or a promise)
The load method of jQuery (which you are using) offers a callback function "complete". See
http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
$("#div").load("content.php", {}, function(){alert(1)});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a lack of understanding of how to approach this task from the outset. I would suggest you look in to how asynchronous operations work in javascript.

What you're trying to achieve here can be achieved with something like this:

```
$.get("content.php", function( data ) {
  $("div").html(data);
  if (data.indexOf("hello") > -1) {
    alert("Hello, world");
  }
});
```

Comment: Looks good, however, it is not updating automatically anymore as it did earlier. And yes, I lack an understanding because I know almost nothing about JavaScript. I'm just a simple PHP kid.

Comment: Not a personal jab @NilsGarland, more of a suggestion that you read up on it a bit more before trying to implement this kind of thing. When you say updating automatically, is that because the contents of content.php changes? If so you can wrap the above function in your original setInterval function to achieve the result (something like that should never be used in production though by the way)